# Amazon S3 stream and removal of download option

Tags: amazon-s3

Title says it all.

I am currently running a website where members are able to stream video directly from my bucket on S3. However, the player also provides a download option. How do I remove this option?

Thanks in advance.

Vincent

Answer (score 0):

From the S3 console, select your videos (you will have to do it one by one) and modify the permissions:

[image]

If you are uploading your videos programmatically you can do this then or by updating the object properties.

You can modify your permissions to a bucket level if you want this for every object in your bucket by selecting Properties (in the right corner of the console once you are in your bucket) and then permissions. Or you can do it programmatically.

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html) you can find more information about ACL fro S3.

Comment: If I remove the open/download option for "everyone" the stream won't show on my website. I just get an access denied message.

Comment: I am not sure what specifically I should add to my bucket policy. I gave skimmed the link you posted but I can't exactly see what condition I need to apply.

Comment: Are you using CloudFront too or S3 only?

Comment: Permissions also says CloudFront Origin Access I.

Comment: The link you have posted talks about putting a referer condition in the bucket policy it not how to actual remove the download option from the S3 player. Or do I get something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't.

One option you can try is to configure [RTMP Streaming Distribution](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-rtmp.html) on your bucket and stream video using [RTMP player](http://flash.flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/rtmp.html).

In this case you should disable public access to your files and give access only to streaming distribution identity.

Solutions that are able to download RTMP streams are not so common (it was a proprietary protocol for a long time)